# Degree, degree program, field of study, or discipline?

Tags: thesis

I am currently writing my Master's thesis (in English, which is obviously not my native language) and on the title page I want to include that it is for "Computer Science". However, I come across different (probably most of them false) terms (used by my peers) of how to denote it. Is it:

- Degree: Computer Science (I think not, since the degree is M.Sc)
- Degree Program (ditto)
- Field of study
- Discipline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, a typical phrasing is:

A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the Master of Science degree in Computer Science

underneath the title. This is not quite set in stone as one could add the name of the institution and one usually does add the advisor or the thesis committee. In general, just find other accepted theses in your department and look what they did.